# Comparing strings from user input in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, if-statement

I was wondering what the best method would be for deciding between 3 choices of user inputted strings and if it is not one of the 3 choices listed, the program will terminate itself. After it has been decided that the user input is correct, the program will choose one of the strings and implement its specific function. Here is the code I have so far:

```
cout << "Specify one of these methods to sort: size, length, publisher" << endl;
        cin >> sort_method;

        if (sort_method == "size" || "length" || "publisher")
        {
           //decide which method was chosen and implement function
        }
        else if (sort_method != "size" || "length" || "publisher")
        {
             cerr << sort_method <<" is not a valid method." <<endl;
            exit(2);
        }
```

It runs and compiles I just can't get it to differentiate between the 3 options which is why I have not written the functions for each yet. Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: To save typing but get a slightly less efficient solution, you could use `static const std::set<std::string> choices = { "size", "length", "publisher" };` and then `if (choices.count(sort_method) != 0)` to check if it's one of those strings.

Answer (score 5):

You have to check `sort_method` explicitly against each of the values. `||` doesn't work like an in clause or directly in English.

```
    if (sort_method == "size" || sort_method == "length" || sort_method == "publisher")
    {
       //decide which method was chosen and implement function
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this out and see if I can get it to work

Comment: Actually this mistake comes from a misunderstanding (or, generously, a colloquialism) of English. It's technically no more valid there than it is here!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit English has no official standard, it is defined by its use!

Comment: @NeilKirk: I hear this a lot and it seems silly. Yes, it's defined by its use, but if it were not defined by its use _in aggregate_ then as a language it wouldn't be much good to anybody. There obviously must be some _de facto_ standard to some degree, because the entire purpose of a language is to facilitate the communication of ideas between persons, which is impossible without a common grammar and vocabulary. That's why we have dictionaries. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ Does language evolve? Yes, of course, naturally. But is it a free-for-all? No. We say there are grammatical "rules" in order to try to keep it as stable as possible (a language that changes every day, or per individual, is useless) and to avoid misunderstandings. In this case, amusingly, the misunderstanding was quite literally a misunderstanding in translation, between the OP and his C++ compiler. :) If people were less haphazard with their spoken language then perhaps the OP could have saved some time.

Comment: If you wanted Mexican or Italian for dinner, would you say, "For dinner I want Mexican or for dinner I want Italian", or would you say, "For dinner I want Mexican or Italian."?

Comment: English is a messed up language because its users are merciless thieves. They see words they like, they loot. A word lifted from Hindi, as I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Going to pitch a slightly different take. Why test twice?

```
if (sort_method == "size")
{
    // do size stuff
}
if (sort_method == "length")
{
    // do length stuff
}
if (sort_method == "publisher")
{
   // do publisher stuff
}
else
{
    cerr << sort_method <<" is not a valid method." <<endl;
    return 2;
}
```

Do not call `exit` without a really, really good reason. `exit` drops everything and ends the program. It does practically no clean up. No destructors are called. Practically no resources are freed. It shouldn't be used unless you have to kill the program and kill it dead immediately.